# How can a planet's seasons be only controlled by either its land, sky or water?

Tags: planets, atmosphere, weather, ocean, natural-resources

I have a planet established (similar to Earth) which instead of countries has 3 main zones of habitation: land, water & sky. Each supernatural inhabitant looks after one natural part of this planet depending on which of the 3 zones they live in eg. one inhabitant on land might look after all mountains, another inhabitant in the sky might look after the rain, another in the water might look after rivers etc etc.

I am trying to work out a way to tie seasons into this type of world structure but it's a bit tricky to categorize because seasons tend to get affected by phenomena across all 3 zones. This doesn't have to be completely scientifically accurate but realistic enough for suspension of disbelief. For example, Spring would be probably the easiest to categorize as it largely concerns the growth of flora on land so I would imagine the inhabitants of the land zone could look after this. Summer perhaps could be theoretically next easiest since it is largely concerned with increasing temperature/sunlight which the sky is most responsible for. Of course the land and oceans also play a part in planet temperature but I need to draw the line somewhere. Autumn and Winter are the trickiest for me to categorize, since Autumn for example (like Spring) is concerned with changes in flora but also sunlight and weather changes which is the sky. What would be the best way to attempt to categorize seasons or have a particular zone responsible for it?

I hope I've done a detailed enough summary of the issue/world without delving into the lore and other intricacies. Happy to add more details as suggested/needed.

Comment: Haven't you answered already by stating that this planet has supernatural inhabitants?

Comment: Yes but I'm asking which of the 3 zones should be responsible and for which seasons in a way that semi-realistically makes sense as per natural phenomena. Eg. do land inhabitants look after Spring only or Spring & Autumn, do sky inhabitants look after Summer etc? Is that clearer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Based on primordial evolution.

Life first sprung from the ocean, so that is spring time. The time when creatures crawl out of the sea to the land, the time when the bounties of the sea flood the land with growth, when the rising temperature fills the air with hot moisture.

After life sprung out of the ocean, it was involved in a host of reactions, hot and ready. Land, the place of volcanoes, warm blood, and fire. Summer. The burning heat of the land spreads storms through the sea and sky, and the rich resources of the sun are given to all.

The sky is the time of autumn. Dead leaves float through the sky, and animals and birds fly seeking resources. It is a time of wild abandon as everyone seeks to embrace the storm and fight for whatever they need to survive winter.

Winter is the broken time. A time when the magic of all three seasons fades, and dead souls and beings from other realities seek to pierce their way in. It is not a true season, but a time of horror and pain. But, it is also a time of growth. Many ancient secrets and secrets never thought to exist in this world can be found in winter, and a skilled magic user can gain great power in the dead times of winter from their otherworldly or dead invaders.